# Java Arraylist Program Failing Test

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I am creating a program that when given a list, returns a new integer list where the first two elements remain the same, and where each element after is the median of the three elements ending in that position in the original list. For example, given the list: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`, the program would return: `[1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`.

This is the code I've written where I'm getting the correct results, but it is failing my tester. I'm not sure if I'm missing an odd case.

Comment: So what is your tester testing? Have you debugged through that failing test step by step?

Comment: it's a tester used in my class. I can post the code from it?

Comment: I would focus on providing a [mcve], with just the test situation that's failing. If you think your code is correct, you should carefully examine the test that's failing - do you agree with what it's testing?

Comment: @BeanieLeung I totaly agree with Jon, that a minimal example would be best. Buit still i would suggest that you post you test code too, it is a relevant part of your auestion and example.

Comment: I posted the tester

Comment: **each element after is the median of the three elements ending in that position in the original list** Can you explain this. What happens for the last value in the list?

Comment: the last value of the new list would be the median of the last value, the second last value, and the third last value of the original list. so in the example, the last 3 values of the original list is 6, 3, 8. the median is 6, which is why the last value of new list is 6.

Comment: it's the test data for my class, so I didn't create it. but people from my class said they were passing the test, so it must be possible

Comment: D'oh! You're right: it's seeding the RNG with a known value, so the "random" test data and its CRC are, in fact, completely predictable.  The test seems sound enough, then...

Comment: Please if you have, provide the seed, cause then we can run the Test too, but still i think i have already found the what was missing, see answer below

Comment: That passed the tester! thanks Samuel!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you missed some cases:
Your code does not calculate the median if one ore more numbers are equal.

Solution whitch will work, based on your Code:

```
    public static List<Integer> method(List<Integer> items) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int size = items.size();
    if (size == 0) {
        list = Arrays.asList();
    } else if (size == 1) {
        int first = items.get(0);
        list.add(first);
    } else if (size == 2) {
        int first = items.get(0);
        list.add(first);
        int second = items.get(1);
        list.add(second);
    } else {
        int first = items.get(0);
        int second = items.get(1);
        list.add(first);
        list.add(second);
        for (int i = 2; i < size; i++) {
            int med;
            if (items.get(i) <= items.get(i - 1) && items.get(i) >= items.get(i - 2)
                    || items.get(i) >= items.get(i - 1) && items.get(i) <= items.get(i - 2)) {
                med = items.get(i);

            } else if (items.get(i - 1) <= items.get(i) && items.get(i - 1) >= items.get(i - 2)
                    || items.get(i - 1) >= items.get(i) && items.get(i - 1) <= items.get(i - 2)) {
                med = items.get(i - 1);
            } else {
                med = items.get(i - 2);
            }
            list.add(med);
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```